# Unchecked call to map(Func1(<? super T, ? extends R>) as a member of raw type rx.Observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have written the following code to integrate generics into the following method. As evident I'm quite a newbie with Generics (haven't created them myself before). The following method is generating weird warning

```
private static PublishSubject mPublishSubject;

public <T> void register(final Class<T> type, Action1<T> observerAction) {
        mPublishSubject.filter(new Func1<T, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(T o){
                Timber.e("Filter(): object type: %s typeClass is: %s", o.getClass(), type);
                if(o.getClass().equals(type)) {
                    Timber.e("Filer() return true");
                    return true;
                }
                Timber.e("Filer() return false");
                return false;
            }
        }).map(new Func1<T, T>() {
            @Override
            public T call(@NonNull T o) {
                Timber.e("Map(): object received from filter: %s", o);
                return o;
            }
        }).subscribe(observerAction);
    }
```

Following are the warnings that I'm getting.

```
Unchecked call to map(Func1(<? super T, ? extends R>) as a member of raw type rx.Observable.

Unchecked call to subscribe(Action1(<? super T>) as a member of raw type rxObservable.
```

What do these warnings mean & where am I making mistake?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `mPublishSubject`. I'd guess that it's raw.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have updated the code

Comment: @AndyTurner Please see the updated code

Comment: Yep, your [`PublishSubject` is raw](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html). You need a type constraint on it, like `PublishSubject<Foo> mPublishSubject;`.

Comment: How would I fix it?

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't want to specify a specific type since PublishSubject will be taking objects of several types

Comment: By the looks of things (based on your type constraints here), `mPublishSubject` should be a `PublishSubject<Object>`. Note, however, that your filter should be `Func1<Object, Boolean>`, and your map should be `Func1<Object, T>`, and should cast the result before returning it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yep that's a good way of doing it. I just put a suppress warning lint annotation on the method for now. Let's see how the CI server handles it